# PHP CodeIgniter models with the same name

Tags: php, codeigniter, namespaces, codeigniter-3

I need your help, please!
I have 2 models with the same name

1.... application/admin/user/models/User_model.php, with this code:

```
 <?php 
        defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

        class User_model extends CI_Model

     ?>
```

2.... application/front/user/models/User_model.php, with this code:

```
<?php 
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class User_model extends CI_Model
 ?>
```

Both classes without differences. 
I need to use `application/admin/user/models/User_model.php`
from `application/front/user/controllers/User.php`

I tried to do the following changes:
If I add in `application/front/user/models/User_model.php` the namespace like this code:

```
<?php namespace customers;
        defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

        class User_model extends \CI_Model
 <?
```

And from `application/front/user/controllers/User.php`, I call `application/admin/user/models/User_model.php` always gives me an error as `application/front/user/models/User_model.php` was not loaded.

If I delete the namespace from `application/front/user/models/User_model.php` my code always goes to this mode  NEVER to `admin/user/user_model`.
I need to AVOID change `admin/user/User_model.php` because a lot of classes uses this MODEL.I only can change `front/user/User_model.php`
But I need to USE `admin/user/user_model`.

I call application/admin/user/models/User_model.php like this:

```
$this->load->model('user_model');
```

I need to load application/admin/user/models/User_model.php

Please help me!!!!
Thx!
Ani

Comment: Show your `config.php`, please. Might be you configured to load models from: `front/user/models`.

Answer (score 3):

That is simply not possible, since Codeigniter doesn't support Namespaces

Usually you would see an error like

```
Fatal error:  Cannot declare class `User_model`, because the name is already in use
```

But Codeigniter prevents this, because it doesn't load any models which are already loaded. You can see this [here](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Loader.php#L267).

So the only way out of your misery is to simply rename your models - even if you don't want to ;)

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps you

**You can created subdirectory in models like this :**

```
application/models/admin/User_model.php

application/models/user/User_model2.php
```

Load the model like this:

```
   $this->load->model('admin/User_model');
   $this->load->model('user/User_model2');
```

you should assigned your model to a different object name you can specify it via the second parameter of the loading method:

**Use them like this :**

```
   $this->load->model('admin/User_model', 'admin_model');

   $this->admin_model->some_method();

   $this->load->model('user/User_model2', 'user_model');

   $this->user_model->some_method();
```

For more : https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html

Comment: imho - that wouldn't work - if he uses the same class name it only get `admin/User_model` instantiated, and since CI doesnt support Namespaces the only way out here is to rename that class...